# Only receive unique warning messages

Tags: r, warnings, unique

Warning messages are a good information i want to know. But i just want to know it one time!

So this function throws 2 different warnings and repeats it 20 times.

How can i tell R to only print unique warnings. Im looking for a gerenal solution.

```
Warning messages:
1: NAs introduced by coercion
2: In sqrt(-1) : NaNs produced
```

Here is my example:

```
foobar <- function(n=20) {
    for (i in 1:n) {
        as.numeric("b")
        sqrt(-1)
        }
}

foobar()
```

Comment: Not possible. R can't know if a warning fits your definition of unique since those warnings are thrown by different function calls. Any way to implement this would be slow and counter productive (since you want to know if warnings occur repeatedly).

Comment: my definition of unique is the definition of base R. So it should work.

Comment: If two different functions give you the same warning, would you consider these different warnings? I would.

Comment: in a deeper sense of course not, but i would already be happy to have only the "string content wise"-unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return only unique warning strings, use

```
unique(warnings())
```

Now, a problem you may have is that your function has more than 50 warnings, in which case `warnings()` will not catch them all. To workaround this, you can increase `nwarnings` in options to e.g. 10000 as suggested in the [help page of warnings](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/warnings.html).

```
options(nwarnings = 10000)
```

Example:

```
foobar <- function(n=20) {
    warning("First warning")
    for (i in 1:n) {
        as.numeric("b")
        sqrt(-1)
    }
    warning("Last warning")
}

foobar(60)
unique(warnings())
## Warning messages:
## 1: In foobar(60) : First warning
## 2: NAs introduced by coercion
## 3: In sqrt(-1) : NaNs produced

op <- options(nwarnings = 10000)
foobar(60)
unique(warnings())
## Warning messages:
## 1: In foobar(60) : First warning
## 2: NAs introduced by coercion
## 3: In sqrt(-1) : NaNs produced
## 4: In foobar(60) : Last warning

options(op)
```

Comment: This looks quite possible, productable and fast. Thank you.